# Can I set 2 address at a time in google map.?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hi I have to set two address at a time in google map. User provides these two address. after submitting I have to show these two address on map.

Comment: Which google Maps Api do you use? V3 or V2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be only one center on map. But, you can add many Gmarkers to a map
refer to: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers

Answer (score 0):

How do you implement Google Maps in your website? A Wordpress plugin? Maps API?

If you wanna create a static map with multiple address:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red|color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false